# Upload to webserver Perl both Ends

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi, multipartform-data

I have two Linux boxes.  One is far away.  I provide computing services to my far-away Linux box
with a LAMP (Linux Apache Mysql Perl )server.  One day, I thought it would be nice to have a script to easily ( my far away staff is not computer literate ) transfer files from there to here.  Figured that it would be easy enough to do a file upload via CGI.  And given that the server is https:, I get the encryption for free.   Been fighting with that for a few days now, nothing works.  Samples that I have found on the web do not work.  The documentation of the involved packages is simply too vague.

**Server side:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;
use Sys::Syslog;
use Data::Dumper;

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS = 0;


my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
my $upload_dir = "/var/my_safe_dir_writable_by_user_nobody";
my $query = new CGI;

#my $filename = $query->param( 'upload' );
my $filename = $query->param( 'filename' );
openlog( 'bare_upchuck.cgi','nodelay,pid','local1' );

if ( !$filename )
    {
    print $query->header ( );
    syslog( 'debug', "No filename!" );
    exit;
    }

# remove any absolute directories
my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '..*' );
$filename = $name . $extension;

# remove any spaces.
$filename =~ tr/ /_/;

# remove any unsafe characters
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;

# untaint the filename, taking only safe characters.
if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ )
    {
    $filename = $1;
    }
else
    {
    die "Filename contains invalid characters";
    }

syslog( 'debug', "now filename is $filename" );
syslog( 'debug', CGI::Dump() );

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload($filename );

if( !defined $upload_filehandle )
    {
    syslog ( 'debug', "upload_filehandle is undefined!" );
    }
else
    {
    syslog ( 'debug', "upload_filehandle is $upload_filehandle" );
    }
open( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while( <$upload_filehandle> )
    {
    print UPLOADFILE;
    }
close UPLOADFILE;
```

**Client side:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file;
my $result;
my $message;
my $filePath = '/where_files_to_upload_are';

$file = $filePath . '/' . "stuff.pdf";  #tryit

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = $ua->request( POST 'https://www.jm-properties.com/jt5/upchuck/bare_upchuck.cgi',
      Content_Type => 'form-data',
      Content => [ Content_Type => "application/pdf",
                   filename => "stuff.pdf",
                   Upload => ["$file" ]
                 ]
);

print "\nRESPONSE -- \n" . $req->as_string;

print $req->content;
# Check the outcome of the response
if ($req->is_success)
    {
    print $req->content;
    }
else
    {
    print "\n in else not success\n";
    }
```

...The server side mostly uses CGI.pm, and the client side - LWP::UserAgent.  What's happening is that the file does not seem to transfer.  The server side fails with an undefined $upload_filehandle.   Doing an strace on the client shows that the file is being opened and read.

The filename is seen by the server, and successfully untainted.  But no actual file seems to be up there ( in the server ).  Maybe somebody who's been there and done that can see something obvious?  I've been beating my head against the wall for a few days now, it's starting to hurt :).

Possible problems might include the Perl data structures on the client side for setting up the upload.  Also - a wrong filename being transferred to the server, and therefore the $query->upload() call failing.  But I really don't know.  And I don't even know how to approach
the troubleshooting.  Since the server side script is a CGI, I can't really use the Perl debugger on it. I tried the debugger on the client side, and that seems to be doing sensible stuff.  It does get to HTTP::Common::Request::Post, and as I said, strace verifies that the file is being opened and read.
Samples of this that I have found on the Web are quite old, and API's have drifted....

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `rsync` might be more straightforward since you want to transfer files and have shell access on both boxes

Comment: Really, what's wrong with `scp` or `rsync`? Those give you the encryption for free, too.

Comment: Honestly, probably nothing.  I just didn't think of those.

Answer (score 2):

OK,  This is what I did.  I didn't really get it working, but I made substantial progress, and as someone here suggested, I moved on to a different technology.

To divide the problem into pieces, I wrote a fake "webserver" that sat on port 8080 and did nothing but output incoming net requests to STDOUT.  I then piped those to a file.

Each form tries a different upload script.  One of them was the fake server.
By uploading from a browser to the fake server, I captured a complete dump of what a real, working
file upload looked like.

Then I ran my perl script on the remote machine trying to upload to the server, and captured a dump of what my bad upload looked like.

Problems were instantly obvious, and I was able to play with the script at the client end to get plausable output.

HOWEVER, try as I might, I was not able to get CGI.pm to accept that output at the server.  I beat my head against the wall for days.  It would get the filename, but the magic to open the filehandle for the internally generated temp file was returning undef.

THEN, I recoded the server side in PHP ( about which I know approximately squat ) and got it working in 15 minutes.

I hope this will save somebody else a bit of grief.  The CGI.pm upload facility is both badly documented and broken.

I tried to insert my code here, but do not have the time or strength to manually insert 4 spaces before every line.